# Additional menu item popping in submenus

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu

I just want to make/add a Menu (Ads) that contains two submenus (View, Manage). My code is written below. The problem is that I don't know why it's popping another submenu in the main menu.

```
function Ad_menu() {
    // Main menu
    add_menu_page( 'Ads', 'Ads', 'manage_options', 'ad_menu', 'Main_Menu');

    // Submenus
    add_submenu_page( 'ad_menu', 'View', 'View', 'manage_options', 'View', 'View');
    add_submenu_page( 'ad_menu', 'Manage', 'Manage', 'manage_options', 'Manage', 'Manage');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'Ad_menu');
```

Comment: Please use proper English, punctuation, readable code formatting etc. Questions are references to other users and people take their time to help you for free, so take the time to format your question as good as possible.

Comment: Try to give meaningful/unique names to each the `slug` and the `callback`: [Function_Reference/add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) As you're using, it will only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third menu item that appears (in fact, the first) is the main menu:

[image]

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'Ad_menu');

function Ad_menu()
{
    //Main menu
    add_menu_page( 
        'Ads page title', 
        'Ads menu title', 
        'manage_options', 
        'ad_menu_slug', 
        function(){ echo '<h1>Main menu</h1>'; }
    );
    //Submenus
    add_submenu_page( 
        'ad_menu_slug', 
        'View page title', 
        'View menu title', 
        'manage_options', 
        'ad_view_slug', // <-- Put main menu slug here
        function(){ echo '<h2>Views submenu</h2>'; }
    );
    add_submenu_page( 
        'ad_menu_slug', 
        'Manage page title', 
        'Manage menu title', 
        'manage_options', 
        'ad_manage_slug', 
        function(){ echo '<h2>Manage submenu</h2>'; }
    );
}
```

If you change the first submenu slug to `ad_menu_slug` (the main menu slug), the result will be this:

[image]

Comment: I have included my view and manage submenu pages on this menu page(Ads) through view and manage functions, but now they are showing up in the ads menu page.

Comment: As I understand it, you ***don't want*** to join the 3 menus in 1, is it? So, why adding "manage" to the main menu?

Comment: I want a main menu(ads) having 2 submenus(view & manage). Now i want to show my view & manage codes in different pages not in the main menu page.

Comment: So what's the problem? You only have to change the `Views` submenu slug, as shown in the Answer. Leave "Manage" as it is.

Comment: Ya that worked fine for me,thanks for that. But now my view and manage pages are shown on the same main menu page.

Comment: View part will also have some code that i don't want to show in main menu.

Comment: What you describe is another problem and you should post a new Question, if it was necessary. I added a comment in the Q explaining where you may be getting it wrong.